# Regex in java code for comma separated strings surrounded with single quotes

Tags: java, regex

I want to generate a regular expression for extracting string tokens from comma separated tokens surrounded with single quotes.

For example: `'ad2&fs'df','sdfsg34fb5bg','rfrg#d,fg'`

Here, I want to get the following tokens:

```
ad2&fs'df
sdfsg34fb5bg
rfrg#d,fg
```

The tokens can contain alphabets, numbers and special characters including comma and apostrophe (single quote).

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: I had tried many expressions but it got very complex and did not work

Answer (score 0):

This could will help.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String s=  "'ad2&fs'df','sdfsg34fb5bg','rfrg#d,fg'";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("','|^'|'$")));
}
```

O/P :

```
[, ad2&fs'df, sdfsg34fb5bg, rfrg#d,fg]
```

This code will give you an additional empty String at index 0 because of the first `'`. You could just ignore it

Answer (score 0):

//use this simple regex pattern

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "'ad2&fs'df','sdfsg34fb5bg','rfrg#d,fg'";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*)','(.*)','(.*)'");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    boolean match = matcher.matches();

    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
}
```

}

Output is as follows

ad2&fs'df

sdfsg34fb5bg

rfrg#d,fg

hope this helps.

Comment: It can have any number of tokens not necessarily three

Comment: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("('(.*)','(.*)','(.*)')*?");    would enable you get more tokens. Hope this helps